# O(m+n) vs O(m) /O(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Different algorithms have different time complexity. I've been curious about this one too much.

O(m+n) represents a linear function, just similar to O(m) or O(n), which also represent linear functions. How is O(m+n) any different from O(m) or O(n)? They both represent linear time. In the case of O(n)/O(m), we neglect the other terms and just take the highest degree. Even in the case of the following equation: T(n)=n+1+n+1; we make T(n)=2n and thus make it O(n). Anyhow, we do not take into account the other parts of the equation.

I did read some articles on this and I didn't quite understand what those meant because according to those articles(or maybe I misinterpreted), m and n are for two variables i and j, but if that's the case, then why do we write two-pointer algorithms as O(n^2).

All this is very confusing for me, please explain to me the difference.

Comment: Maybe you should include some concrete examples of algorithms in your question. E.g. an algorithm that's O(n^2) that you'd expect it to be O(m+n) or the other way around.

Comment: Does [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/what-is-the-meaning-of-omn) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m` and `n` might have very different values, that is why `O(m+n)` is different from `O(m)` or `O(n)` (but similar to `O(max(m,n))`)

Simple example:
Breadth-first search on graphs has complexity `O(V+E)` where `V` is vertex count, `E` is edge count.

For dense graphs `E` might be as large as `V*(V-1)/2`, so `E~V^2` and we cannot say that complexity is `O(V)`  - in this case it is `O(V^2)`.

On the other side - very sparse graphs, where `E` is very small compared with `V`. In this case we cannot say that `O(E)` - in this case it is `O(V)`.

And `O(E+V)` is valid in all cases.